# :greater_than_or_equal_to, :numericality, and other symbols with meaning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols

A line of my of code is as follows:

```
validates :price, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01}
```

`:price` is the only symbol that I defined. `:numericality` and `:greater_than_or_equal_to` both have some meaning of comparison.

1. What are these things called?
2. Where can I find documentation on them? There seems to be a ton of these symbols that do random things. Are these instance methods? Where can I find a list of them?

Comment: which things confusing you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbols are like strings. They sometimes are used in constructions that look like method invocations, but they are not methods.

In your case, method `validates` accepts two parameters, a symbol and a hash. `:numericality` and `:greater_than_or_equal_to` are just keys in a hash, nothing more. What will `validates` do with them, no one knows (except `validates` itself). So, in order to find out, you need to read documentation on `validates` (and related rails guides, maybe).

Answer (score 0):

The webpage here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html should show what validations are available.

The symbols you refer to don't have a 'meaning' per se, but tell the methods what to do when passed as variables.

Validates is simply a method call, but in ruby  the parentheses are option, sometimes putting them in makes it easier to conceptualise it, such as

```
validates(:price, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01})
```